# Objective-c [Xcode] CCAnimation not working, cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

i have two animations declared in the player class, and i want to run then from another class but i can't here's my code (If you can't read it here it's on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/iy0eFMWL):
player.h

```
    @interface Player : CCSprite {
    CCAnimate *animationOllie;
    CCRepeatForever *repeatNormal;
    }
```

player.m:

```
    @implementation Player

    -(id)initWithFile:(NSString *)filename
    {
if (self = [super initWithFile:filename]) {
    self.velocity = ccp(0.0, 0.0);


    CCAnimation *ollie = [CCAnimation animation];
    [ollie setDelayPerUnit:0.05f];
    [ollie addSpriteFrameWithFilename:@"ollie1.png"];
    [ollie addSpriteFrameWithFilename:@"ollie2.png"];

    animationOllie = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:ollie];


    CCAnimation *normal = [CCAnimation animation];
    [normal setDelayPerUnit:0.05f];
    [normal addSpriteFrameWithFilename:@"normal1.png"];
    [normal addSpriteFrameWithFilename:@"normal2.png"];
    CCAnimate *animationNormal = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:normal];

    repeatNormal = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:animationNormal];

    [self runAction:repeatNormal];

        }
        return self;
    }
    -(void)animateThePlayer {
        [self stopAction:repeatNormal];
        [self runAction:animationOllie];
    }
```

And in the GameScene Class:
GameScene.h:

```
    @interface GamePlayLayer : CCLayerColor {
        float yVel;
    }
```

GameScene.m:

```
    #import "Player.h"

    @interface GamePlayLayer()
    {
        Player *player;
     }

    @end

    @implementation GamePlayLayer

    -(id) init
    {
        if( (self=[super initWithColor:ccc4(255,255,255,255)] )) {

    player = [[Player alloc] initWithFile:@"normal1.png"];

    [self addChild:player];

    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

    player.position = ccp(85,70);


    [self schedule:@selector(update:)];

        }
        return self;
    }

    -(void)update:(ccTime)dt {

        if (player.position.y > 70) {
            yVel -= 0.1;
        }
else {
    if (yVel != 5.5) {
        yVel = 0;
        player.position = ccp(player.position.x, 70);
    }
}
player.position = ccp(player.position.x, player.position.y + yVel);

    }


    - (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    yVel = 5.5;
        [player animateThePlayer];
    }
```

And that's it, it builds fine, and everything works but when i click the layer it crashes and i get this message:

> 0x1df609b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2,
>   address=0xf

What can i do? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing - you try to use autoreleased object. `animationOllie` will be released after your init method.

The second mistake is that you cannot reuse actions. When you need to run action, you have to recreate it.

Comment: Thnaks, So i should create a method for each animation and call them when i need? because i did that and, only the CCAnimation is working (ollie), the CCRepeatForever is not (repatNormal). I've made some changes: http://pastebin.com/NNk7dnNt

Comment: check how often fo your normalAnimate method is called. from your update method i can assume that normalAnimate can be called every tick. in this case you will not see any animation, because it will be stopped every tick and started again.

Comment: Thank-you! that was exactly the problem